# Absolute element outside of overflow-x scroll not visible

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` inside a `div` that has a `height` and `overflow-x` applied, so the `ul` is not visible. I tried to use different CSS rules like `z-index`.

I am searching for a CSS-only solution.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.container div {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3f3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    test 1
    <ul>
      <li>menu 1</li>
      <li>menu 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    test 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. The restriction on links to offsite resources is there for a reason. If you add the relevant code to the question here, more people will see it and you will get more accurate answers more quickly. 2. 'I am searching for a CSS-only solution' so why tag JS? 3. What exactly is the expected outcome? If the content is outside the bounds of the element, then of course it's not going to be visible. What are you expecting any solution to this to be other than 'move the content in to the visible area of the element, or add scrollbars'

Comment: the bar (div with scrollbar) with the elements is on the bottom of a page and i want to show the ul to the upside of the bar but if the bar has overflow-x: scroll overflow-y is hidden even if i set overflow-y to visible. the expected outcome is to showing the ul over the edge of the bar.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work in this way.
First remove `top: -100px;` because of that it is not showing one reason.
And if this is require that you need to change structure
in this structure it will not work mostly